# Where should we continue ongoing discussion on closed questions?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/deleted-comments) was closed as a duplicate while discussions as to the best answer were ongoing, and while useful information was coming out. Where should we go to continue discussion on questions that have been closed? Should we copy all the comments and answers to the duplicate question?

Comment: It's being continued here: [How can we improve our guidance about the comment practices?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/614)

Answer (score 4):

The question was closed so not to spread the answers between multiple threads. If you raised some new set of issues in comments as part of a side discussion, you can certainly ask about *those* issues as another meta post.

Your question exemplifies why we ask users *not* to carry on extended discussions in comments. You're going against the grain in trying to figure out how to continue your *other* discussions. Stack Exchange is designed specifically to make discussions difficult.

After someone asks a question, members of the community propose answers. Others vote on those answers, and the answers with the most votes rise to the top. That's the entire purpose of Stack Exchange; You don’t have to read through a lot of discussion to find the information you need. If you start posting useful information throughout the comments in a threaded pseudo-discussion, the entire *purpose* of Stack Exchange becomes moot. 'Might as well go join any one of the thousands of phpBB forums on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to comment on closed questions.  It simply prevents new answers.  If you want to continue the discussions there, feel free.

If you're not getting quite the immediate gratification you're looking for, you might try chat.  It's a better place for discussions.

Comment: It's not about gratification. Closing a question as duplicate is a strong indicator that the reader will find everything they want on the other question. That is not so in this case. Closing the questions steers people away from the discussion.

Comment: @DJClayworth: We had a conference with the SE guys on this and are working on a solution to that dup issue. Please stand by. _(this comment will be deleted when this issue is fixed.)_