# Should we discourage comments which tend to deviate from the op's question?

Tags: discussion

As I understand the comments section it exists to obtain clarification of a question, or convey to the poster some misstep in their questions. Recently however; some comments have been used by members to discuss ideas which have no relation to the question originally asked. That sort of commentary is not helpful to either the site or to clear up the misunderstanding of the poster. While I realize that I have been lured into some of these discussions myself, should we not discourage this sort of behavior? I cite this question as an example: [What is the meaning of 'the Sun and the Moon' in Joseph's dream?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37011/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-sun-and-the-moon-in-josephs-dream)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, we should discourage non-constructive comments, and we already do. You can always flag comments that you think are too chatty or not constructive. I think the mods do a pretty good job at deleting non-constructive comments when they find them and flagging helps the mods find them faster. Here's some meta posts that parrot that sentiment:

- [How can we improve our guidance about the comment practices?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/how-can-we-improve-our-guidance-about-the-comment-practices)
- [Comment Deletion](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546/comment-deletion)
- [Guidelines on flagging obsolete comments](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2235/guidelines-on-flagging-obsolete-comments)
- [Personal Opinion answers and comments: Flag, downvote, comment, or do nothing?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/personal-opinion-answers-and-comments-flag-downvote-comment-or-do-nothing)
- A very important one: [But can't I just say one thing?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/but-cant-i-just-say-one-thing)
- [What makes a comment obsolete?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4026/3961)
- [Where are all the comments?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/728/where-are-all-the-comments)
- [Deleted comments](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/603/3961)
- Probably the most relevant for you personally (because you are the one who asked it):
  [How can we stop the comments from being an area for arguments?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-can-we-stop-the-comments-from-being-an-area-for-arguments)